# How to install Docker Engine on Microsoft's CBL-Mariner 2.0 Linux?

Tags: docker

I am trying to use the [CBL-Mariner 2.0](https://microsoft.github.io/CBL-Mariner/announcing-mariner-2.0/) Linux as the OS for my Azure virtual machines (Azure VMSS). I want to use it to run Docker containers. Hence, I need to install docker engine on the Mariner 2 VM. Are there anyone who already figured the installation out?

I am following the [Fedora installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/fedora/). However, I did not succeed.

```
weng5e@5e-mariner2-dev-2302 [ ~/lt ]$ sudo dnf -y install dnf-plugins-core
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:27 ago on Fri Feb 10 18:22:00 2023.
Package dnf-plugins-core-4.0.24-2.cm2.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
weng5e@5e-mariner2-dev-2302 [ ~/lt ]$ sudo dnf install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:38 ago on Fri Feb 10 18:22:00 2023.
No match for argument: docker-ce
No match for argument: docker-ce-cli
No match for argument: containerd.io
No match for argument: docker-compose-plugin
Error: Unable to find a match: docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

The moby engine is already added to the official Mariner package feed. So, installing moby engine instead of docker ce would work.

```
sudo tdnf install moby-engine moby-cli ca-certificates -y
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```